# overlay area not restricted to div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I am having difficult making an overlay/hover command in CSS work correctly. I have 4 separate div's side by side, and when I put an overlay on it to make the picture fade on hover, it puts the hover effect on the other div's with the effect as well regardless of whether or not you are hovering over that div. I tried to restrict the hover to an image in the div, but could not The page that is having the trouble is- http://www.peel-lawfirm.com/practice-areas/workplace-injury

Here is my CSS code-

```
.fade {
   opacity: 0.5;
   transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   }

   .fade:hover {
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 10;
  left: 0;
  right: 10;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.7;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
```

And here is  my html for that portion of the page-

```
<div class="container">
  <p>
    <h3 style="text-align:center;">Practice Areas</h3>
  <hr>
  </p>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <p><jdoc:include type="modules" name="box1" /></p>  
            </div>
             <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <p><jdoc:include type="modules" name="box2" /></p>
             </div>
     <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <p><jdoc:include type="modules" name="box3" /></p>  
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <p><jdoc:include type="modules" name="box4" /></p>      
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: do you want the effect on all 4 boxes because only 2 have the overlay setup?  In general, just move the hover to the 2nd part: .container .overlay:hover {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `.container:hover .overlay {...}` which means when the `.container` div is hovered it will apply for all `.overlay` divs inside it. You need to apply the `:hover` only for the desired `.overlay` divs inside the `.custom` divs.

Change `.container:hover .overlay {...}` to `.custom:hover .overlay`

Comment: That worked, thank you! I did not realize it was applying to the whole container. Now that it is working properly I can apply the effect to the rest of the boxes. Thanks again!